# How can call method from parent component - ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to implement "react-native-easy-toast" in many pages of my project. So I planned to make a react component so I can use the same component from different pages. But to show Toast need to call `this.refs.toast.show('hello world!');`, So how can call it from my component?

```
<Toast
      ref="toasterror"
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
      position='top'
      positionValue={10}
      fadeInDuration={750}
      fadeOutDuration={2000}
      opacity={0.8}
      textStyle={{ color: 'white' }}
 />
```

https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-easy-toast#getting-started

Thanks.

Comment: add an Id to this Toast and then do a $('#toatadId').toast.show()

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a ref of a component by:

```
onRef = component => {
  this._toast = component;
}

render() {
  return <Toast ref={this.onRef} ... />;
}
```

Then you can call methods of the component on `this._toast`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the component as follows

**Toast.js**

```
import Toast from 'react-native-easy-toast'
import React from 'react'

class ToastInstance extends React.Component {

    showToast = (duration) => this.refs.toast.show('hello world!', duration);

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.show) {
            this.showToast(nextProps.duration)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Toast
                ref="toast"
                style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
                position='top'
                positionValue={10}
                fadeInDuration={750}
                fadeOutDuration={2000}
                opacity={0.8}
                textStyle={{ color: 'white' }}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default ToastInstance
```

**Usage**

```
import Toast from './Toast'


state = {  
        show: false,
        duration: 1000
    }

_renderToast = () => {
        this.setState({show: true})
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({show: false}), this.state.duration)
    }

render() {
 const {show, duration} = this.state
 return (
   <View>
     <Text onPress={this._renderToast}>Show Toast</Text>
     <Toast show={show} duration={duration}/>
   </View>
 ) 
}
```

You'll need to add features to it according to your convenience